# Windows firewall rule disables 'itself'

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-firewall

I have a server running Windows Server 2012 r2. On this server I set-up a rule in Windows Firewall to allow specific ports used in NAT.

This rule works great, but every day or so it seems to just disable itself. I simply login to the server and enable it again and all is fine.

I can't find anything on this so hoping for some help.

Comment: Is the server a member of a domain, and if so, are there any GPOs being applied to it that have Windows Firewall settings in them?

Comment: Yes to domain, 2 GPO's but nothing in either to do with firewall (mostly just settings to do with offline files and account policies)...

Comment: If you're able to re-enable the rule then it isn't being managed by a GPO. Is the rule being disabled for a particular firewall profile? If so, is it possible that the server is having problems detecting the correct network profile?

Comment: The rule is set to apply to all 3 profiles... I'm assuming the only way to 'know' whether this is the case is to swap to the different profiles and wait to see if it disables?